# Problems merging two tableviews into a tabbar with Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one tabbar with several views, one with a tableview connected to Core Data. Now I've made one more tableview in a different project, and I want to merge it to my first project. This isn't new to me, I've done it before in another project where I had three tableviews with different core data tables, all working good. So I thought this would be a walk in the park.

In my AppDelage.m and .h I've added and copied all the code for the managedObjectContext to managedObjectContext2. And made a new navigation controller, "navigationController2".

```
ProtokollList *protokollList = (ProtokollList *)[navigationController2 topViewController];
    // Set its managedObjectContext property to the managed object context 
    protokollList.managedObjectContext2 = self.managedObjectContext2;

    // Get the root view controller; it's in the topViewController property of the navigation controller
    KortKategori *kortKategori = (KortKategori *)[navigationController topViewController];
    // Set its managedObjectContext property to the managed object context 
    kortKategori.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

And then in my ProtokollList.m I've changed managedObjectContext to managedObjectContext2. And made necessary connections in MainWindow.nib.

But when I try to run the project I get this error message:

```
2011-07-24 18:22:58.188 Kortspel[1346:207] Unknown class ProtokollList in Interface Builder file.
2011-07-24 18:22:58.198 Kortspel[1346:207] -[UIViewController setManagedObjectContext2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d13c40
2011-07-24 18:22:58.199 Kortspel[1346:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setManagedObjectContext2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d13c40'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fab5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010ff313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fad0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f1c966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f1c522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Kortspel                            0x00001f28 -[KortAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 709
    6   UIKit                               0x002c4ce2 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1252
    7   UIKit                               0x002c6d88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    8   UIKit                               0x002d1617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    9   UIKit                               0x002c9abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    10  UIKit                               0x002cef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x01903992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00f8c944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00eeccf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee9f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee9840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee9761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  UIKit                               0x002c67d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    18  UIKit                               0x002d2c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    19  Kortspel                            0x00001c40 main + 102
    20  Kortspel                            0x00001bd1 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I don't know it says that it doesn't recognize "ProtokollList" class, because it's defined in ProtokollList.h.

Does anyone have any idea? This is the last step before launching!

EDIT:
If I try to blank out:

```
/*
ProtokollList *protokollList = (ProtokollList *)[navigationController2 topViewController];
    // Set its managedObjectContext property to the managed object context 
    protokollList.managedObjectContext2 = self.managedObjectContext2;
*/
```

I can open the project, but when I click on ProtokollList-tableview I get this new error message:

```
2011-07-25 20:06:56.588 Kortspel[3205:207] Unknown class ProtokollList in Interface Builder file.
2011-07-25 20:07:01.585 Kortspel[3205:207] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x590f3f0
2011-07-25 20:07:01.587 Kortspel[3205:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x590f3f0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01106313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb40bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f23966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f23522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x004882b7 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834
    6   UIKit                               0x00485d88 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x00339677 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 132
    8   UIKit                               0x00346708 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773
    9   UIKit                               0x00343844 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42
    10  QuartzCore                          0x01f52a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01f54ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01efa0b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01efb294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01efb46d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f9389b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f286e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef11d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef0840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef0761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x019091c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01909289 GSEventRun + 115
    22  UIKit                               0x002d9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    23  Kortspel                            0x00002524 main + 102
    24  Kortspel                            0x000024b5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Best regards,
xqtr

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I understand that the critical point is the warning about IB (did not notice it at start)...

Could you check that ProtokollList.h and ProtokollList.m are effectively assigned to the target you are building? (I think so, otherwise you would have more linking problems, anyway, this is a basic check).

If this is ok, then I would simply try a clean and rebuild all.

If this does not fix the problem, then this might mean that the linker is not including ProtokollList.m in the final binary because of some optimization (the class is possibly never referenced in the rest of your code, just in Interface Builder). The fix for this is adding `-all_load` to the linker flags of your project.

If this does not help, I am very sad but I have no more suggestions...

You are calling:

```
    protokollList.managedObjectContext2 = self.managedObjectContext2;
```

and no property named `managedObjectContext2` is found in `protokollList`. This can be inferred by the line:

```
-[UIViewController setManagedObjectContext2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d13c40
```

So, you should possilby define `managedObjectContext2` in `protokollList` (which should be a `UIViewController`).

EDIT;

```
interface ProtokollList : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {           
      NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController2;
      NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;
@end
```

Comment: Hi @sergio, and thank you for your reply!

In ProtokollList.h I've already defined managedObjectContext2:



@ interface ProtokollList : UITableViewController 

<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
 NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController2;
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;
}

@ end


Or have I done anything wrong?

Comment: you should be missing the property definition, see my edit, and don't forget about the `@synthesize` in `.m` file...

Comment: No, I have the property definition as well, so that can't be it. 

@ property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController2;
@ property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;

and @ synthesize fetchedResultsController2, managedObjectContext2;

Comment: Thanks again for your replies and the new edit. I've tried them all, but I get the same error message. It's really annoying. I would post the whole code, but can't because of too few posting points. I'll post it in some hours.

Comment: check also that `[navigationController2 topViewController]` in your appDelegate returns a real object of type ProtokollList and that the cast is not playing some trick...